# What is an ideal way of designing a pipeline in AWS where we have both batch and streaming sources trying to update a table using PUSH mechanism?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, streaming, spark-streaming, batch-processing

I am planning to have a table in S3, preferably a parquet one (using HUDI since we anticipate upserts too). Downstream applications will be writing to this table in a fixed format as and when the data gets created. These downstream applications can be both batch or streaming. Batch applications can sometimes write millions of records at one go during backfills (200M+) or 20M in an incremental fashion on a daily cadence.

[image]
Concern is, can large bursts of batch data throttle queue or consumer?